# What does ${1:0:2} mean in this context?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am looking into the code displayed below and it checks the input if the row/column arguments start with either `-r` or `-c`. 
What does `${1:0:2}` mean in this context?

```
rowArgName="-r"
colArgName="-c"
if [ "${1:0:2}" != $rowArgName ] && [ "${1:0:2}" != $colArgName ]
then
   echo $correctCmdMsg >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You should include the shell you are using into the question. Which is probably `bash`.

Comment: This seems to be done to parse command line arguments. Probably you'll want to know about `getopt` or `getopts` to make your life easier (or the life of whomever did this).

Answer (score 34):

It's a Substring Expansion (subclass of Parameter Expansion) pattern of shell.

The format is:

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

and indexing starts at 0.

Say, you have a variable `foo`, then `${foo:0:2}` yields the first two characters (from position 0 the next 2).

**Example:**

```
$ foo=spamegg
$ echo "${foo:0:2}"
sp
```

In your case, the first number, `1`, refers to variable name `$1`, which is the first argument passed via command line (in the main program) or the first argument passed to the function.

So in your case, `"${1:0:2}"` will:

- start extracting the substring starting from index 0 i.e. first character
- and continue upto next two characters

so after the operation you will get the first two characters (indexed at 0 and 1) of the input string.

The `[ "${1:0:2}" != $rowArgName ]` and `[ "${1:0:2}" != $colArgName ]` are checking if the output subtring is equal to some other strings.

Comment: Essentially it is checking for whether or not user provided $1 with `-c` or `-r` ,which probably better have been implemented with `getopts`

Answer (score 15):

A small extract from `man bash`:

> #### ${parameter:offset:length}
>
> **Substring Expansion**.  Expands to up to `length` characters of  the
>            value  of  `parameter` starting at the character specified by `offset`.  If parameter is `@`, an indexed array subscripted by `@` or `*`,
>            or  an  associative  array name, the results differ as described
>            below.  If `length` is omitted, expands to the  substring  of  the
>            value of `parameter` starting at the character specified by `offset`
>            and extending to the end of the value.  `length`  and  `offset`  are
>            arithmetic expressions (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION below).

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple substring extraction from a variable.  The variable in question is the first parameter to the script (which is `1`).

If I have a variable, FOO, I can see the first two characters of its value with `${FOO:0:2}`.  The same thing is being done in your example with the first argument.